# Group sum distinct values from another field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have two tables that are joined via a left join on the customer number as follows:

```
          Customers                                Transactions
AccountNumber   CustomerBalance         AccountNumber  TransAmount  TransDate
1                $100.00                 1               $100.00     8/1/2017
2                $200.00                 2               $200.00     8/2/2017
3                $300.00                 4               $50.00      8/2/2017
4                $400.00                 4               $100.00     8/4/2017
5                $500.00                 4               $50.00      8/5/2017
6                $600.00                 6               $100.00     8/4/2017
```

These Tables are combined and end up looking like the below table:

```
          Combined Table
AccountNumber   CustomerBalance     TransAmount  TransDate
1                $100.00             $100.00     8/1/2017
2                $200.00             $200.00     8/2/2017
3                $300.00             
4                $400.00             $50.00      8/2/2017                
4                $400.00             $100.00     8/4/2017                
4                $400.00             $50.00      8/5/2017
5                $500.00            
6                $600.00             $100.00     8/4/2017
```

What I need is to sum the balance column but only for each account number once,
so Account number 4 appears 3 times because of 3 transactions but I only want it to sum the balance once. I also need this to happen on a group level of crystal reports so if I were to group my data based on accounts 1-10 and then 11-20 and so on it would only give me each separate group's balance.

Is this possible in crystal reports because I am stuck on the Idea of using running sums to only show the account balance once but crystal doesn't let you summarize a running sum field and I know the workaround for that is to do a running total sum for the header while printing records however I don't know how to transfer that over to a group level/header on crystal report.

Expected Result for the sample data sum should be $2100.00

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: show the real expected  result  .. not word...

Comment: What should end up as $2100? Please show an example of how you want the end product to look. Also, why are you keeping a total balance instead of a running balance? This should be as easy as saying `SUM(TransAmmount)`

Comment: I need the balance because it is the original balance for that account. So if original balance is $400.00 and the sum(TransAmount)=$200 then the remaining balance is $200.00.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(CustomerBalance)
from (select distinct AccountNumber, CustomerBalance from table) as e
```

It's been a while since I've used Crystal Reports, so I'm not sure if this works in that program, but I tried it in SQL Server and got the correct answer.

Comment: That works on microsoft sql studio for me but not on crystal itself as far as the grouping goes.